# Странное поведение присваивания

Tags: функции, golang

Обнаружил странное поведение в Go, связанное с объявлением структур. Я не могу записать возвращаемое значение в поле структуры с использованием оператора `:=`. Если же это переменная, то сделать я это могу

```
package main

import (
    `fmt`
)

func foo1() (int, bool) {
    return 1, false
}

func foo2() (int, error) {
    return 1, nil
}

type MyStruct struct {
    X int
}

func main() {
    // Не работает
    var x MyStruct
    x.X, y := foo1() // non-name x.X on left side of :=
    fmt.Println(x, y)

    // Работает
    var y bool
    x.X, y = foo1()
    fmt.Println(x, y)

    // Работает
    var q int
    q, z := foo2()
    fmt.Println(q, z)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего странного, всё как в [спецификации](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .
identifier = letter { letter | unicode_digit } .
```

`x, y := 1, 2` это то же самое, что `var x, y = 1, 2`. Так же, как вы не можете объявить переменную с именем `x.X` написав `var x.X, y = 1, 2`, вы не можете сделать `x.X, y := 1, 2`.